# How do you configure PHP to use mysql instead of sqlite

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have PHP 5.3 and MYSQL 5.1 installed on centos.

PHP uses SQLite as default, how can I configure PHP to use MYSQL instead?

Comment: could you provide some code how you access the database?

Comment: There are sitting in your server to get this. But don not use `mysql_*` as it is deprecated. What do you want to use `mysql_*`?

Comment: It's not a coding problem - it's configuration. I am installing Drupal which only allows me to select sqlite, because PHP comes with an sqlite configuration as default. I need to configure PHP to use mysql instead of sqlite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if drupal doesnt recognize mysql as valid database backend, then your mysql doesnt seem to be installed correctly. try

```
yum install mysql mysql-server php-mysql
chkconfig --levels 235 mysqld on
/etc/init.d/mysqld start
mysql_secure_installation
```

and restart apache with

```
/etc/init.d/httpd restart
```

then try again to configure drupal.